# Column 'xxx' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I'm trying to group a table by using a race (Raza in spanish) and that value is a foreign key, down below is the query.

```
SELECT PJ.Id,
       PJ.Nombre,
       Raza.Nombre,
       Clase.Nombre,
       PJ.Nivel,
       PJ.Fuerza,
       Pj.Destreza,
       Pj.Constitucion,
       PJ.Inteligencia,
       PJ.Sabiduria,
       PJ.Carisma
FROM Personaje AS PJ
     INNER JOIN Clase ON PJ.Clase = Clase.Id
     INNER JOIN Raza ON Pj.Raza = Raza.Id
GROUP BY Raza.Nombre;
```

Comment: If I asked you to group a class of students by their sex, how many rows will you get? 1. Male 2. Female so two rows. Now imagine i say I also want the names of each student beside the group. You will say: well i cannot give you just 2 records anymore if you also want the names. I can give you the names but the sexes will now repeat. Well the query you have written is causing the sql server to ask you the same question: make up your mind on whether you want grouped data or individual records.

Comment: You might just want `ORDER BY Raza.Nombre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To appear in the select line when a group by is present. You need one of the following to be true about the column

It needs to be an aggregate function (such as sum, min, max etc )

It needs to be part of the group by

Most of your columns In this query are not either of these so the error is being shown about the first error.

For example

PJ.ID this column isn't contained in a function. And isn't part of the group by. So fix this you need to add PJ.ID to to group by

For example

```
 GROUP BY Raza.Nombre, PJ.ID
```

This needs to be used done for every single column you want in the select

Answer (score 0):

Here is general rules whenever you are using `GROUP BY` clause :

1. If a select block does have a `GROUP BY` clause, any column specification specified in the `SELECT` clause must exclusively occur as a parameter of an aggregated function or in the list of columns given in the `GROUP BY` clause, or in both.
2. The expressions that are used to form groups also occur in the `SELECT` clause. However, that is not necessary. An expression that occurs in the `GROUP BY` clause can appear in the `SELECT` clause.
3. An expression that is used to form groups can also occur in the `SELECT` clause within a compound expression.
4. If an expression occurs twice or more in a `GROUP BY` clause, double expressions are simply removed